# Problema con set

Tags: python

Estoy realizando un if en el cual digite 2 alfabetos separados por comas y los una, para ello estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
if op1 == str(2):
         c1 = set(input('Ingrese el alfabeto 1 separado por comas: '))
         c2 = set(input('Ingrese el alfabeto 2 separado por comas: '))
         print(f'A U B: {c1 | c2}')
```

Los une sin problema pero al momento de imprimir la respuesta ingresando valores para `c1 = 'a,b,c' y c2 = 'd,e,f'` me sale de la siguiente manera:

```
A U B: {'e', 'f', ',', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'}
```

Porque me muestra desordenado y porque en una posición me sale `','` que podría estar fallando?
Gracias

Comment: La documentacion de [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) dice que esta desordenado.. lo otro, supongo que es por como se arma set... yo no soy experto.. pero suena logico.... "A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La respuesta sencilla es que te falta usar un método llamado `split()`. Pero vamos con la explicación.

#### Set

Un set, como ya te lo han dicho, es un conjunto de datos **desordenados** y **sin repetición** que puede contener a cualquier tipo de dato inmutable, un `set` también es un tipo de dato mutable (a diferencia de `frozenset`) pero no permite la asignación de valores (item assignment) y tampoco puedes acceder a sus índices por la notación de corchetes (`object[index]` por lo que no es un objeto subscriptable) pero puede ser recorrido y también podemos añadir y quitar elementos.

#### Problema

Al hacer `input('Ingrese el alfabeto 1 separado por comas: ')` simplemente estas pidiendo los valores, si por ejemplo ingreso `Holas, que hay` el resultado de la función `input` será `Holas, que hay` y si a eso lo convertimos en un set nos dará tu resultado, si quieres separar los valores por comas y obtener esos valores separados se usa el método `split()` y como argumento se le pasa el caracter por el cual se hará la separación.

```py
c1 = input('Ingrese el alfabeto 1 separado por comas: ').split(",")
print(c1)
```

Y hacemos:

```
Ingrese el alfabeto 1 separado por comas: a,b,c
>>> ['a','b','c']
```

Como vemos ya no se nos toma la coma y a esa lista ya la podríamos convertir a `set` y obtendríamos `{'c','a','b'}` (lo mismo pero desordenado). Tu código tendría que ir así:

```py
if op1 == str(2): #puedes poner "2"
         c1 = set(input('Ingrese el alfabeto 1 separado por comas: ').split(","))
         c2 = set(input('Ingrese el alfabeto 2 separado por comas: ').split(","))
         print(f'A U B: {c1 | c2}')
```

#### Observación

Ahora tomaré un escenario hipotético, donde en vez de introducir letras separadas por comas introducimos palabras separadas por comas. Para este caso ya no funcionaría como pensamos.

```py
c1 = set(input('Ingrese el alfabeto 1 separado por comas: ').split(","))
print(c1)
```

Si ejecutamos y probamos obtendremos:

```
Ingrese el alfabeto 1 separado por comas: Holas,que,hay
>>> {'que', 'hay', 'Holas'}
```

Aquí se nos crea un `set` pero de acuerdo a las palabras que ingresamos, esto por que al hacer la separación nos quedaría esto: `['Holas','que','hay']` y no nos quedará cada letra separada, lo quen tendríamos que hacer sería eliminar la coma y hacer un set de todo el string completo.

```py
#usamos el método replace para reemplazar las comas por un string vacío
c1 = set(input('Ingrese el alfabeto 1 separado por comas: ').replace(",", ""))
print(c1)
```

Podemos hacer eso o simplemente pedir que se ingrese los valores pero no separados por comas :)

##### Nota

Para el *desordenamiento* del `set` no hay una solución, siempre estarán los datos desordenados, si quieres tenerlos ordenados puedes usar listas pero claro ya no podrías hacer operaciones de conjuntos como lo haces con un `set`.

Answer (score 0):

En una búsqueda rápida me encontré con [este resultado](https://j2logo.com/python/tutorial/tipo-set-python/). Primer párrafo:

> El tipo set en Python es la clase utilizada por el lenguaje para representar los conjuntos. Un conjunto es una colección desordenada de elementos únicos, es decir, que no se repiten.

El `set` entonces es desordenado por definición.

En cuanto a la coma, es uno de los carácteres que ingresaste ¿por qué no estaría? Del mismo tutorial:

```py
# Crea un conjunto a partir de un string
# Los caracteres repetidos se eliminan
>>> a = set('Hola Pythonista')
>>> a
{'a', 'H', 'h', 'y', 'n', 's', 'P', 't', ' ', 'i', 'l', 'o'}
```